# How to expose Dropwizard Metrics to Prometheus

Tags: java, dropwizard, prometheus

I have implemented a Java web service using [Dropwizard](http://dropwizard.io/). Now I want it to also expose [Prometheus metrics](https://prometheus.io/).

I have followed [this](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/issues/101#issuecomment-177280816) pretty straight-forward example. However, the endpoint at http://localhost:9090/metrics is still not exposed.

Here's the relevant code:

Dependencies in the `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_dropwizard</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.prometheus/simpleclient_servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
        <artifactId>simpleclient_servlet</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Java code:

```
import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;
import io.prometheus.client.CollectorRegistry;
import io.prometheus.client.dropwizard.DropwizardExports;
import io.prometheus.client.exporter.MetricsServlet;
[...]

public class MyApplication extends Application<MyServiceConfiguration> {

@Override
public void run(final MyServiceConfiguration configuration,
        final Environment environment) {
    final MyServiceResource resource = createResource(configuration);
    environment.jersey().register(resource);

    registerHealthChecks(environment, resource);

    registerMetrics(environment);
}

private void registerMetrics(Environment environment) {
    CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry = new CollectorRegistry();
    collectorRegistry.register(new DropwizardExports(environment.metrics()));
    environment.admin().addServlet("metrics", new MetricsServlet(collectorRegistry))
            .addMapping("/metrics");
}
```

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the admin port? /metrics is nested under the admin app.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the endpoint http://localhost:8081/metrics actually exists.

Comment: I want to expose dropwizard metrics to Prometheus and I am stuck. Could you please provide the whole example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember default dropwizard configuration has the admin app on a different port. That's where you'd find the metrics servlet.